# Enumerating Polygonal Subdivisons

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $P$ be a given polygon in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that all the vertices lie on integral points $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$. An integral polygonal sub-divison of $P$ is a subdivison of $P$ into integral sub-polygons. I would like to know:

If there is an algorithm to generate all such sub-divisons?  I would prefer an easier to implement (possibly less efficient) algorithm over a more efficient one. I do not want probabilistic algorithms unless they have a very high efficiency.
 To illustrate the problem here are some pictures:

The initial polygon is like this:

[image: Integral polygon]

An allowed sub-divison

[image: A valid Integral Subdivison]

An invalid sub-divison

[image: Not a Valid Integral Subdivison]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is P convex? What is an integral sub-polygon? What is a polygonal division? Perhaps you should clarify...

Comment: 1. Please edit the question with clarifications, as suggested by Aryabhata.  2. In addition, what have you tried?  There seems to be a straightforward recursive algorithm: it might inefficient, but it will be simple and meet your requirements.  We expect you to make a significant effort on your own before asking, and to show us in the question what you've tried.